# If velocity $v^\mu$ is a contravariant tensor of rank 1 then shouldn't force be a mixed tensor of type (1,1)?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, tensor-calculus, velocity, covariance

The covariant derivative of a (1,0) tensor is a mixed tensor (1,1) but this doesn't seem to be the case. Force is always regarded as a rank 1 tensor. The derivative of velocity is acceleration. I'm very confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force is not the covariant derivative of the velocity, but a contraction of it:

$f= m \nabla_{v}v$